# Which trophies can only be obtained through the Trophy Shop?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I have read that some of the trophies in Super Smash Bros. 4 are available exclusively through the trophy shop. For example, alternate colored fighter trophies are a Trophy Shop exclusive ([source](http://www.ssbwiki.com/trophy_shop)).

Which trophies can only be obtained by purchase in the trophy shop?

Answer (score 2):

The only Trophy Shop exclusives are the Character Alternate Trophies which will start to appear in the shop after you clear Classic with the chosen fighter.  (Wii U Only)
Example: Clearing Classic with Sheik on Wii U will unlock the Trophy in te Trophy Shop, if you keep checking, the trophy will appear eventually.

If you are looking for Final Smash Trophies, you get those from clearing All-Star Mode.  (Wii U Only)

The only other trophies that are exclusive to a specific game mode are the Trophy Rush Exclusives, trophies that you can only find in the Trophy Rush game mode.

Answer (score -2):

Alternate colored fighter trophies will be available to purchase as the player clears Classic Mode with each fighter. Unlike most random trophies, they are found exclusively at the Trophy Shop.

This is the only information currently out there about exclusive trophies that are available in the shop. I will update my answer with my own findings if I find something new.

[***SOURCE***](http://www.ssbwiki.com/trophy_shop)

Comment: Quoting the source linked in the question and claiming no other data doesn't really add anything that wasn't already in the question. I'm hoping for a more definitive answer.

Comment: Well I'm not claiming anything. There is no other data that states anything about any other exclusives available in the shop. I am just clarifying the information that is available and where I got it.